# How to output/return a table of Variable values in a Snowflake QUERY

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to write a Snowflake query that returns the values of variables in a table format.  I am doing this to be able to write a query and then later on easily change the query into a stored procedure without having to refactor all the variables.  The below code is my attempt at doing this.  Why am I getting errors when I attempt to run this query?

```
DECLARE
    ThirteenMonth DATE;
    RollingStartDate DATE;
    ReportDate DATE;
    
BEGIN
    ReportDate := IFNULL(:ReportDate, CAST(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE));
    ThirteenMonth := DATEADD(MONTH, -13, :ReportDate);
    RollingStartDate := DATEADD(MONTH, -25, :ReportDate);
    
    INSERT INTO IDENTIFIER($Results)(ReportDate,ThirteenMonth, RollingStartDate)
    SELECT :ReportDate, :ThirteenMonth, :RollingStartDate;
    
    RETURN TABLE(Results);
END;
```

I am currently getting the following error:

Error: Session variable '$RESULTS' does not exist (line 317)

Comment: Please update your question with error message(s) you are getting

Comment: @NickW: Added the current error. Thank you.

Comment: So you haven’t created a session variable called RESULTS but are trying to reference it in your code. The error seems to be pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few problems. Without the header it's not clear what the inputs are, but it may look like this signature. To dynamically construct a SQL statement and execute it, you can create a string and `execute immediate` using the string you created. Also, in order to use session variables such as `$Results` you'll need to `execute as caller`.

```
create or replace procedure foo(ThirteenMonth DATE, RollingStartDate DATE, ReportDate DATE)
returns table()
language sql
execute as caller
as
$$
DECLARE
    ret RESULTSET;
    sql STRING;
BEGIN
    ReportDate := IFNULL(:ReportDate, CAST(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE));
    ThirteenMonth := DATEADD(MONTH, -13, :ReportDate);
    RollingStartDate := DATEADD(MONTH, -25, :ReportDate);
    
    INSERT INTO IDENTIFIER($Results)(ReportDate,ThirteenMonth, RollingStartDate)
   
   sql := 'SELECT \'' || :ReportDate || '\'::date "ReportDate",\'' || :ThirteenMonth || '\'::date "ThirteenMonth",\'' || :RollingStartDate || '\'::date "RollingStartDate"';
   ret := (execute immediate :sql);
    
   RETURN TABLE(ret);
END;
$$;

call foo('2022-12-01'::date, '2022-06-01'::date, '2022-12-15'::date);
```

Output:

| ReportDate | ThirteenMonth | RollingStartDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-15 | 2021-11-15 | 2020-11-15 |

Comment: I am attempting to write a QUERY that can be easily converted to a stored procedure.  So, I am not trying to write a stored procedure.

Comment: If it's not inside a stored proc, then what are the variables?